# Are IV–I progressions easier for guitarists than V–I progressions?

Tags: guitar, physiology

Discussions of embodiment have become more and more prominent in the world of music theory. In a nutshell, claims regarding embodiment use the physical act of performing (and what the performer's body must do) as a means towards understanding analysis. (This is a really oversimplified view of embodiment, but it works for this question.)

This got me thinking: are IV–I progressions somehow easier to play for guitarists than V–I progressions? Can we understand the prevalence of plagal cadences (as opposed to authentic V–I cadences) in pop music as in some way related to the physical act of playing these chords?

Comment: If the answer happens to be yes, that would be really interesting! My current hunch is that it has a very small effect if any (and is also likely very hard to determine empirically). Neat thought-provoking question, I had never even considered this!

Comment: Since it’s just a difference of inversion, it’s literally the same difficulty to play either progression. That said, I have consciously and assertively favored writing riffs that are fun to play on guitar - that feel good in my hands. I don’t think there’s a clear music theoretical basis or pattern that is easy to summarize about what feels good and what doesn’t on guitar.

Comment: This sort of (for me) seems to base on the fact that a lot of pop music (particularly the songs which contain that IV>I) would be written on guitar, or at least use guitar as a main instrument for the song. Not sure how true that might be. The change from V>I is no harder to execute than IV>I. Amen to that..!

Comment: This is a particularly specific expression of the idea of embodiment.  What made you think about those particular chords on that particular instrument?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can't think that ease of fingering is an overwhelming push away from V-I. After all, for any given IV-I, the *reverse* motion would be V-I in another key.

I've always just thought that V-I has a cheery and slightly pompous finality about it that isn't necessarily appropriate to the themes that came to typify rock. V-I seems a little to me like the musical equivalent of *...and they all lived happily ever after. The end!* - which may not be the way that your story of teenage angst actually does end... (this is a very subjective statement of course, but arguably for any musical genre to gain traction, you need a bunch of people with similar subjective understandings!)

It's partly also perhaps that many pop and rock progressions try to give a sense of potentially endlessly going round and round (for easy dancing?), so again, something that has come to be seen as an 'ending' or strong resolution isn't necessarily what you want. There are even songs that seem to avoid ever coming down firmly on the I chord.

Comment: I think the middle paragraph is a great explanation. V-I isn’t new, fresh, revolutionary, or close to any kind of rock esthetic.

Comment: @ToddWilcox When writing that it occurred to me that blues (where rock arguably has some of its angsty roots?) features plenty of V-I cadences - but then maybe that's a good illustration of where rock in the latter half of the 20th century has developed its bluesy and folky influences towards a more explicitly doom-laden harmonic language..?

Comment: Did you mean IV-I cadences in blues? I'm used to blues being I - IV - I - V - IV - I.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I do mean V-I - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve-bar_blues#Standard_progressions - though of course the version you mention is extremely common too (It's given as the archetypal 'Shuffle blues' later down that page).

Comment: Not to mention that the most stereotypical Blues _ending_ is an almost caricature-romantic chromatic approach to the **Ⅴ**, which is then resolved to... **Ⅰ⁷**!